# UITableView repeating Firebase Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting repeated content from Firebase, and I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. In firebase I have 6 posts. The tableview is populating 6 cells, but all 6 cells have the same data, and the 5 other posts are not there.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    RankingsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RankingsCell"];
    self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
    posts = [ref child:@"posts"];

    [posts observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot)
     {
         for (snapshot in snapshot.children)
         {
             NSString *username = snapshot.value[@"Name"];
             NSString *date = snapshot.value[@"Date"];
             NSString *combatPower = snapshot.value[@"Combat Power"];
             NSString *pokemon = snapshot.value[@"Pokemon"];
             NSString *pokemonURL = snapshot.value[@"Pokemon Image"];
             NSString *picURL = snapshot.value[@"Profile Picture"];
             int CP = [combatPower intValue];

             cell.usernameOutlet.text = username;
             cell.dateOutlet.text = date;
             cell.combatPowerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"COMBAT POWER: %d", CP];
             cell.pokemonLabel.text = pokemon;
             [cell downloadUserImage:picURL];
             [cell downloadPokemonImage:pokemonURL];
         }
     }
        withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
     }];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: dont use firebase data directly like this store it in one array and access it

Comment: I'm not sure how I would store all of those values to an NSArray and then pull them...

Comment: when you got a response then create one  array give value that your snapshot and in table cellrowatindex just access your nsarray

Comment: Sorry, could you show me a small example of what you mean?

Comment: is that Swift code?

Comment: ya swift 2.0 this code working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cellForRowAtIndex:` method is called for "every" cell, so you're not supposed to do your database work in there, it's just responsible for creating "one" cell at a time.

So, move your `observeEventType:` call in `viewDidLoad:` or `viewDidAppear:` like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
    posts = [ref child:@"posts"];

    [posts observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot)
     {
         self.allSnapshots = [NSMutableArray array];

         for (snapshot in snapshot.children)
         {
                 [self.allSnapshots addObject:snapshot];
         }

         [self.tableView reloadData]; // Refresh table view after getting data
     } // .. error ...
}
```

And in `numberOfRowsForInSection:`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section      
{
    return [self.allSnapshots count];
}
```

And in `cellForRowAtIndex:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RankingsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RankingsCell"];

    FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot = [self.allSnapshots objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

    NSString *username = snapshot.value[@"Name"];
    NSString *date = snapshot.value[@"Date"];
    NSString *combatPower = snapshot.value[@"Combat Power"];
    NSString *pokemon = snapshot.value[@"Pokemon"];
    NSString *pokemonURL = snapshot.value[@"Pokemon Image"];
    NSString *picURL = snapshot.value[@"Profile Picture"];
    int CP = [combatPower intValue];

    cell.usernameOutlet.text = username;
    cell.dateOutlet.text = date;
    cell.combatPowerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"COMBAT POWER: %d", CP];
    cell.pokemonLabel.text = pokemon;
    [cell downloadUserImage:picURL];
    [cell downloadPokemonImage:pokemonURL];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: brother tell me that in your code allSnapshots  type ?

Comment: that concept i tell him but he cant catch it

Comment: FIRDataSnapshot* ? You're answering an Objective-C question with Swift, so that may be the problem. I got what you've tried to mention, but it needs a better explanation.

Comment: I made "allSnapshots" a property of FIRDataSnapShot, and did what you said but it's throwing the error on the `[self.allSnapshots.children objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: There is probably a better way to do, but I've edited the answer to add all children snapshots to an array, so you can directly access to it now. (self.allSnapshots is NSMutableArray* now)

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thank you sir!