# How to run a function after another function in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, grand-central-dispatch

I am new to swift 3, and I got stuck to this problem. I have two functions, the first function gets the value of a key in my FirebaseDatabase. The second function displays a the variable retrieved from the FirebaseDatase inside a TableView. The problem is that the second function launches before the first one. This makes the value return nil.

First function:

```
        self.shopItems = [String]()



        databaseRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                for child in snapshot.children {
                    let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
                    let dictionary = snap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                    self.shopItems.append(dictionary["Name"] as! String)

                    print(self.shopItems)
            }

        })
```

The second function:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(4), execute: {
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.shopItems[indexPath.row]
    })
    return cell
}
```

I know i can use the Dispatch-Wait method, but I want the second function to wait until the first one is done. How would i do so?

Comment: I think you only need call `self.tableView.reloadData` after `print(self.shopItems)`

Comment: how do i use closures?

Comment: Objc dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40317957/2124535

Comment: Why are you using `DispatchQueue` in your `cellForRowAt` method? Get rid of that.

Comment: Because the dispatch queue makes it wait for shopItems being inititialized.

Comment: No, that's not correct at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this, as I said in my first comment I think you only need call `self.tableView.reloadData` after `print(self.shopItems)`

```
self.shopItems = [String]()
databaseRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
        let dictionary = snap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        self.shopItems.append(dictionary["Name"] as! String)

        print(self.shopItems)
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

And correctly implement this method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.shopItems.count
}
```

Also update your cellForRow to this

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
    self.cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.shopItems[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You need to call `reloadData` on the main queue.

Comment: I think that the observer callback return in mainThread, ok I will update my answer @rmaddy thanks

Comment: I don't use Firebase so I guess it's possible the closure is always called on the main queue but I wouldn't make such an assumption.

Comment: @rmaddy I think it not necesary as the questioner says it works,  
I don't use Firebase either, but Iam not sure

Comment: Haha, I forgot, I am sorry:) Have a nice day

Comment: @StackOverflow I am Glad to help you, best regards

Answer (score 1):

You are badly confused. You don't call `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`. The system calls it.

If you want to wait and reload your table once the data has finished loading, you should put a call to reloadData inside your `databaseRef.observe` method's closure:

```
    databaseRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
                let dictionary = snap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                self.shopItems.append(dictionary["Name"] as! String)

                print(self.shopItems)

                //Add the line below. 
                //Note that if the closure is called from the background, you'll 
                //need to use GCD to call this method on the main thread.
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

And, if the completion code in your databaseRef.observe method gets called on a background thread then you'll need to wrap that in a call to `Dispatch.main.async()` (or a similar method to invoke the code on the main thread.)

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: You need to call `reloadData` after the loop, not inside it. And it needs to be called on the main queue.

Answer (score 0):

The second function runs when data in the tableview is loaded. When the tableview is created it loads the data from shopitems array into the view. If there are no objects in the array the tableview will appear empty. In order to reflect changes to the shopitems array, in other words reflect that in item has been appended to the array you have to call the appropriate tableview function .

The correct way to do this is to use:

```
    databaseRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
                let dictionary = snap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                self.shopItems.append(dictionary["Name"] as! String)

                let row = self.shopItems.index(of:self.shopItems.last!)
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row:row, section:0)
                tableView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])

                print(self.shopItems)
        }

    })
```

.You will have to create an indexPath using the index of the object in the shopitems array.

The other method is to reload all the data in the tableview after append.

```
    databaseRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
                let dictionary = snap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                self.shopItems.append(dictionary["Name"] as! String)



                print(self.shopItems)
        }

              DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
           }

    })
```

Comment: as @rmaddy says in the comments of Duncan answer "You need to call reloadData after the loop, not inside it. And it needs to be called on the main queue."

Comment: @ReinierMelian reloading data inside the loop would reload each item as it is downloaded. Reloading outside the loop would reload the updates in a batch.

Comment: @rmdaddy I was in the process of writing this when you posted and did not see your response I apologise. There is not need for such hostility I am only trying to help. If any part of my answer helps anyone I am happy. Forgive me if this is not normal, I am relatively new to SO

Comment: @Abishek23 There was no hostility. I simply pointed out a fact, that's all. Please don't take it personally. You should probably delete your answer since it isn't helpful as-is.

Comment: @Abishek23 `snapshot.children` is an array so why you should reload the table on every item? the data is there already you only need reload the table after add all objects to `shopItems` array

Comment: @rmaddy Your comment is hostile. I do not take it personally , it comes across like you took my post personally I am only here to learn. The correct way to update a tableview is to insert items at the index or is it not . reloadData reloads previously downloaded data as well as the new data. So if there were items in the shopitems array already they would be reloaded without need.

Comment: @ReinierMelian well you should not be using reload data to update a tableview ideally. One should use the appropriate insert or delete methods. In terms of user interface, if the reload occurs after each child then you  the tableview would appear to update cell by celll. I am not stating that one has to do it that way.

Comment: Your 2nd set of code shows the call to `reloadData` inside the loop. It should not be inside the loop but after the loop. Your 1st set of code is fine. I never commented on that.

Comment: @rmaddy " this answer provides no additional information and is in fact wrong. " This quote seems to apply to my whole answer? . Secondly reloadData is not the best practice for insertion. In regards to the to the reloadData being inside the loop I have explained it in my comments above. If i am honest I realised it makes sense to be outside the loop but that does not mean it is wrong to be inside the loop. It is as wrong as using reloadData to do insertions.

Comment: Yes, it is wrong inside the loop. Reloading the whole table over and over inside a loop will cause problems. Fix that and I will retract most of my comments because I did misread the first set of code in your answer. That part is fine. But do note that the code in the question requires more fixes than just the code you have in your answer.

Comment: @rmaddy I will make the change as I agree it is more efficient to use it outside the loop. What problems would occur? It would only be inefficient. If you use dispatch_async there should be no problems. If you know of any problems that will occur please let me know it would be good to understand. I use IGListKit instead of collectionviews and tableviews these days and it has removed the need for reloadData and complexity of inserting and deleting.

Comment: @rmaddy  There is no indication of how much of the setup the user has implemented and so I answered it in context, furthermore cellforitem at would not be called if number of rows had not been set therefore I did not see the need for that.